# ion-menu-button not showing on top left of ionic native google map and neither allow map to work properly

Tags: google-maps, ionic4, ionic-native

I want to show the menu-button on google map top left, but when I tried to use  it appears in middle of the map and doesn't allow any functionality of map to work, wherever you click it will open the menu. html is as follows:

`<div id="map_canvas">
    <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
  </div>`

[image: Image of map with ion-menu-button]

But when I use a simple button it works fine but I want menu icon to. The Html is shown below:

`<div id="map_canvas">
    <button (click)="OpenMenu()" >Start Demo</button>
  </div>`

[image: Image of map with simple button]

CSS for both cases is same and as follows:

`#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    <ion-button>
     <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
```